# How to get recursively all analogs from table by an article?

Tags: php, recursion

I've create a simple table of analogs:

```
+----+-------+-------+
| id | sku_1 | sku_2 |
+----+-------+-------+
|  1 | a1    | abcd  |
|  2 | a2    | a3    |
|  3 | a3    | a1    |
+----+-------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

What it mean? It mean that product with article `abcd` has an analog with article `a1`, otherwise for example product with article `a3` has an analog with article `a1`.

How to recursively get all the products from this table by a single article?

My solutions is wrong:

```
// Small Class to get analogs of products
class Analogs {

    public function get_analogs($sku)
    {
        if (!$sku) return false;

        $link = mysql_connect('localhost','','');
        mysql_select_db('test');

        $sku = mysql_real_escape_string($sku,$link);

        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM analogs WHERE sku_1='".$sku."' OR sku_2='".$sku."'");

        while($analogs[]=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
        continue;

        return $analogs;    
    }


    public function MixedAnalogs($sku)
    {
        if (!$sku) return false;

        $link = mysql_connect('localhost','','');
        mysql_select_db('test');

        $sku = mysql_real_escape_string($sku,$link);

        $query = mysql_query("select sku_1 sku from analogs where sku_2 = '$sku' UNION
                              select sku_2 sku from analogs where sku_1 = '$sku'");

        while($analogs[]=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
        continue;

        return $analogs;
    } 


}

$mixed_analogs = AnalogsMix('abcd',$ids=array());

echo "<pre>";
print_r($mixed_analogs);
echo "</pre>";

// Recursive function to get analogs of analog
function AnalogsMix($sku,$ids=array())
{
    $class_analogs = new Analogs();
    $analogs = $class_analogs->get_analogs($sku);

    foreach ($analogs as $analog)
    {
        $cross = null;

        if ($analog['sku_1']==$sku)
        {
            $cross->sku = $analog['sku_2'];
        }
        else
        {
            $cross->sku = $analog['sku_1'];
        }

        $cross->id = $analog['id'];

        if (!in_array($analog['id'],$ids))
        {
            $ids[] = $analog['id'];
            $mixed[] = AnalogsMix($cross->sku,$ids);
        }
    }

    if (isset($mixed))
    {
        return $mixed;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. You don't use `mysql_real_escape_string` to properly escape `$sku`. 2. Note that `mysql_*` functions are deprecated (see the [red box](http://php.net/mysql_query)). 3. What's wrong? What does it output at the moment and what should it output?

Comment: Just to be sure I understand the question, what result do you expect for the example you provided ?

Comment: @Marcel Korpel. I'm not going to use this on my real server, it is just an abstract example. And @Fabien, If I put `abcd` into this, I must get all the analogs, cause `abcd` has analog as `a1`, `a1` has analog of `a3`, `a3` has analog as `a2`, so function must return me all the analogs.

Comment: You still need to escape `$sku` if it can contain `'`, otherwise things will go horribly wrong. Moreover, there are more people that read your code and they might think it's ok.

Comment: Am I right in thinking, that for ABCD you expect a1, which has a3 which has a2. So for ABCD your results will have a1, a3 and a2 as the result?

Comment: @Husman, yes, definitely.

Answer (score 1):

SQL UNION

```
select sku_1 sku from analogs where sku_2 = $yourid
union
select sku_2 sku from analogs where sku_1 = $yourid
```

Then you will get in results only ids of analogs.

Comment: And see what other comrads tell you about proper escaping and depcrecated functions :)

Comment: I've added a method for this. And I'm getting this: $class_analogs = new Analogs();

$mixed_analogs = $class_analogs->MixedAnalogs('abcd');

echo "<pre>";
print_r($mixed_analogs);
echo "</pre>";

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [sku] => a1
        )

    [1] => 
)

Comment: And? Do you want from us to work instead of you? :) We give you an idea -- next actions you should do by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Here, I suppose you have all your pairs in an array. For example, for your example, you would call `analogsOf(array(array("a1", "abcd"), array("a2", "a3"), array("a3", "a1")), "abcd")`.

The idea is that you build a list of analogs containing initially only the string you are looking for and, every time you find an analog, you add it to the list of analogs and reiterate. You do so until you iterated the whole array of pairs without finding anything new.

```
function analogsOf(array $pairs, $key) {
    $res = array($key); // The result, with only the given key
    $i = 0;             // Index of the current item
    $changed = false;   // Have we added an item to $res during that iteration ?

    while ($i < count($pairs)) {
        $current = $pairs[$i];

        foreach ($res as $item) {
            if (($current[0] === $item) && (!in_array($current[1], $res)) {
                $res[] = $current[1];
                $i = 0;  // Reiterate as $res changed
            }
            else if (($current[1] === $item) && (!in_array($current[0], $res)) {
                $res[] = $current[0];
                $i = 0; // Reiterate as $res changed
            }
            else {
                $i++;  // Nothing found here, go to next item
            }
        }
    }

    return $res;
}
```

Note that this code was NOT tested, so there might be a few bugs here and there, but you've got the idea. Also note that I considered you could put the whole database content in an array, but that is probably not possible for obvious reasons, so you will probably have to adapt the code above.

Comment: Is this really scalable? Loading all of your mysql data into an array, makes mysql defunct. You lose the speed and efficiency of a database.

Comment: I know, must be a level, and will be. Now it is only a test.

Comment: @Husman, as I say, no, this is not very scalable as is, and you have to find caching strategies if data is getting bigger and bigger. If scaling becomes an issue, anyway, I think storing analogy links explicitly in the DB will be by far the best option.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for this problem but the main problem in this approach is that.
it can make a loop like `abcd->a1,a1->a3,a3->a2,a2->abcd`. and it make recursive function endless and php throw an error. so you have to check for that if it is a big project.

in my solution i consider it parent-> child relation. and if a child found make it parent and check again and so on until there is no result.

let `abcd` is parent and after first execution `a1` is child and relation is `abcd->a1`. but in next call  `a1` is parent and from first row of table it give a new relation that is `a1->abcd`  and loop is endless. 
To prevent checking in same row i use `ID` of last row from database and it now check row where id != ID (always check other row)

this is function i write, convert it according to your class and store the value in array as you like. I use a string only.
i knew it not a good solution but i works fine.

```
<?php 

mysql_connect('localhost','','');
mysql_select_db('test');

function getSku($sku, $id, $rel = '') {
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM analogs WHERE sku_1 = '$sku' AND id != '$id'" );
    if (mysql_num_rows($query)) {
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
        $sku = $row['sku_2']; //PARENT SKU
        $id = $row['id']; //LAST ID
        $rel .= $row['sku_1']. '-->' . $row['sku_2']. "<br>";

    } else {
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM analogs WHERE sku_2 = '$sku' AND id != '$id'" );
        if (mysql_num_rows($query)) {
            $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
            $sku = $row['sku_1']; //PARENT SKU
            $id = $row['id']; //LAST ID
            $rel .=$row['sku_2']. '-->' . $row['sku_1']. '<br>';
        } else {

            return (string)$rel; //NOTHING FOUND
        }
    }
    return getSku($sku,$id,$rel);    

}

echo $new = getSku('abcd','-1');
```